# How to pass Body Parameters(format) when calling a POST request with Content-Type as form-data in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, api, post, azure-data-factory

I am trying to call API endpoint as a POST and Content-Type as from-data using azure data factory web activity. Tried different way of passing Body parameters but it failed.
Here is the Postman Request.
[image]
Here is the Azure Data Factory Web Activity configurations.(use the body as a json and tried different combinations but all didn't work)

[image]

And above is the error message.
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer helpful ? or did you find a solution

Comment: Actually we don't wanna use powershell. We are using a small .net functionapp to handle it. I wanna know whether we can handle it without functionapp. Basically, what is the correct way of passing body parameters if the content-type is multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

Since your request is seen successfully executing from postman, try copying the  entire body from that and use in web activity.

The format for passing body for a POST request from a web activity is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#request-payload-schema).

Also make sure you have entered valid “**url–Target endpoint and path**”. This is usually seen as Activity requires Public end point but you may have used Private vnet where this is not allowed. Web Activity is supported for invoking URLs that are hosted in a private virtual network as well by leveraging self-hosted integration runtime. The integration runtime should have a line of sight to the URL endpoint.

**Note:** The activity will timeout at 1 minute with an error if it does not receive a response from the endpoint.

Further going through some similar scenarios it is learnt that;

1. Mostly the header is passed as string in WebActivity whereas Postman
   it is integer/long
2. In case your API tries redirecting, it seems that the web activity
   in Azure Data Factory does not currently support following
   redirects, meanwhile Postman and other tools and libraries usually
   follow redirects by default or include a option for handling them.

[Checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#authentication) the supported authentication types in the web activity. If you are trying to authorize your from, try set the following.

**URL:** `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantid>>/oauth2/token`

**Headers:** `Content-Type - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

**Body:** `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<<clientid>>f&client_secret=<<secret>>&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmicrosoft.onmicrosoft.com%2F<<resourceId>>`

**Error code: 2108:**

**Message**: Error calling the endpoint '%url;'. Response status code: '%code;'

**Cause**: The request failed due to an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation, or a timeout.

**Workaround**: Make the API call using Powershell, and call that Powershell script from within Data Factory.

Comment: Issue is `Content-Type is multipart/form-data` in postman not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: you can try the either way, which one do you need. You can try "multipart/form-data" with above configs I mentioned above. If you have binary (non-alphanumeric) data (or a significantly sized payload) to transmit, use multipart/form-data. Otherwise, use application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I can use powershell as a workaround. But its not working with the configs I have provided. I wanna know the what is the body format when we need to pass parameters when the Content-Type is `multipart/form-data`

Comment: [Submit a multipart/form-data file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#example-5--submit-a-multipart-form-data-file) & [specify a list of query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#:~:text=specify%20a%20list%20of%20query%20parameters)

Comment: As per the findings, there is no direct way of calling multipart/form-data using Azure data factory. I have created a .NET function app to handle that.